# (string) LIKE query with join in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two different columns inside the tables using the strings which is only partially common between the two columns of two different table.

How do i combine these two tables:

Suppose if i have 2 tables, table1, table2

```
 ╔════╦══════════════════════════════════╦══════╗
 ║ T1 ║  String1                         ║ snr  ║
 ╠════╬══════════════════════════════════╬══════╣
 ║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood is good but naughty  ║ 5636 ║
 ║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas is bully and fat    ║  148 ║
 ║  3 ║ Jeff Atwood likes skoda and hate ║      ║
 ║    ║ ferrari                          ║  101 ║
 ║  4 ║ Geoff Dalgas is smart but not    ║      ║
 ║    ║  intelligent                     ║  959 ║
 ╚════╩══════════════════════════════════╩══════╝

 ╔════╦══════════════════════════════════╦══════╗
 ║ T2 ║  String2                         ║ bnr  ║
 ╠════╬══════════════════════════════════╬══════╣
 ║  5 ║ Jeff Atwood is good              ║ 1323 ║
 ║  34║ Geoff Dalgas is bully            ║12148 ║
 ║  73║ Jeff Atwood  likes skoda         ║26101 ║
 ║  64║ Geoff Dalgas is smart but        ║56959 ║
 ╚════╩══════════════════════════════════╩══════╝
```

This is what i am trying to acheive

Result:

```
 ╔════╦══════════════════════════════════╦══════╦══════╦══════╗
 ║ T1 ║  String1                         ║ snr  ║bnr   ║T2    ║
 ╠════╬══════════════════════════════════╬══════╬══════╬══════╣
 ║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood is good but naughty  ║ 5636 ║1323  ║5     ║
 ║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas is bully and fat    ║  148 ║12148 ║34    ║
 ║  3 ║ Jeff Atwood likes skoda and hate ║      ║      ║      ║
 ║    ║ ferrari                          ║  101 ║26101 ║73    ║
 ║  4 ║ Geoff Dalgas is smart but not    ║      ║      ║      ║
 ║    ║  intelligent                     ║  959 ║56959 ║64    ║
 ╚════╩══════════════════════════════════╩══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

The only relationship i see is to compare the string1 and string2 (which is partially equal)

This is my syntax:

```
SELECT table1.T1, table1.String1, table1.snr, table2.bnr,table2.T2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.string1 LIKE table2.string2
```

but i get any error that

> There is a chance that you may have found a bug in the SQL parser. Please examine your query closely, and check that the quotes are correct and not mis-matched. Other possible failure causes may be that you are uploading a file with binary outside of a quoted text area. You can also try your query on the MySQL command line interface. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem. If you still have problems or if the parser fails where the command line interface succeeds, please reduce your SQL query input to the single query that causes problems, and submit a bug report with the data chunk in the CUT section below:
>
> ERROR: C1 C2 LEN: 56 57 770 STR:  etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any wildcard characters in the `LIKE` argument, it just does an exact string match. You need to add `%` wildcards:

```
SELECT table1.T1, table1.String1, table1.snr, table2.bnr,table2.T2 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.string1 LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.string2, '%')
```

Comment: okay i tried with the above but it returned empty set, let me write in SQL Fiddle and see if it works

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select ID, String From (
(SELECT t1, string1  FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT t2,string2  FROM table2)) order by ID;
```

Comment: This will not answer your question. I was viewing it on mobile so missed many parts of question.

Comment: (1) output does not have the 5 columns desired; (2) that returns 8 rows; 4 are desired.